# Visa requirements to visit France and the UK for business purposes as a German resident (visa national)

Tags: visas

I am Indian nationality and working in Germany. I hold a German Resident Permit card with a valid work permit until end of 2018. My question is related to Visa. If I need to travel to France or UK for the purpose of attending meetings/trainings, do i need to have Visa for travelling to above countries?

Comment: This are two different questions, as there are different rules for France (as part of Schengen) and the UK (which is not part of Schengen.) Both questions have been asked before and have good answers. I vote to close this question because of that.

Answer (score 2):

For France, you do not need a visa as it is a party to the Schengen agreement. This means, that your German visa / resident permit allows you to visit France freely.

For the UK, you will have to apply for a visa at the UK consulate in Germany.